# Filter django queryset: Query objects with two or more reverse-related objects with a certain identical field value

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-aggregation, django-related-manager

Suppose we have two models like this:

```
from django.db import models

ModelA(models.Model):
    ...

ModelB(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, ..., related_name='b_models')
    some_field = models.CharField(...)
    other_field = ...
    ...
```

What do I do, if I want to get a `ModelA` queryset containing **only** those objects who have **two or more** `b_models` pointing to them that **have the same value** for `some_field`?

Consider this example setup:

```
a1, a2 = ModelA.objects.create(...), ModelA.objects.create(...)

b1 = ModelB.objects.create(a=a1, some_field="foo" ...)
b2 = ModelB.objects.create(a=a1, some_field="foo" ...)
b3 = ModelB.objects.create(a=a1, some_field="bar" ...)
b4 = ModelB.objects.create(a=a2, some_field="baz" ...)
b5 = ModelB.objects.create(a=a2, some_field="foo" ...)
```

In this example the queryset should contain object `a1`, because objects `b1` and `b2` both relate to it **and** both have the value `foo` in `some_field`. (And **not** contain `a2`, because it doesn't satisfy the second requirement.)

I know that I can use `.annotate(models.Count('b_models'))` and then `.filter(b_models__count__gte=2)` to get those instances of `ModelA` with two or more reverse relationships from `ModelB`. But in this example, this would return both `a1` and `a2`. How do I satisfy the second requirement and filter the queryset further?

(Or is there an even better overall approach than my `annotate` clause?)

**EDIT:** To clarify, I should not need to know **what** the **specific value** of `some_field` will be. The second requirement is simply, that the `ModelB` instances are **identical** in their value for `some_field`. So if I were to add

```
b6 = ModelB.objects.create(a=a2, some_field="baz" ...)
```

then the query should return both `a1` and `a2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add another filter, something like `.filter(b_models__count__gte=2, b_models__some_field="foo")`

Comment: No, I am not looking for a solution to the specific case, where `some_field="foo"`. That would be trivial. I just care about objects with identical `some_field` and values (and that have `ForeignKey` to the same `ModelA` instance). I don't know and don't want to know what the specific values will be.